# MySQL Query Not Working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a query I'm trying to build so that I can filter by car brand. But if a certain session variable exists, it'll ask for an extra part to be added to the query which is basically limiting the results to the logged in branch.  Here's the query:

```
$query_AUCTION = "SELECT * 
          FROM at_auction AS a 
          JOIN at_brands AS b ON a.aCarBrandID = b.bid 
      ORDER BY b.brand $orderx";
```

... now this works but where can I add a:

```
"WHERE bid = '{$bid}'"? ...or a... "AND bid = '{$bid}'";
```

It brings up an error.

Comment: "brings up an error" - why do you think you should *not* tell us what that error is?!

Comment: SORRY it was just a check your syntax error!!! Thanks for answers everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert your where clauses BEFORE your order by

```
$query_AUCTION = "SELECT * FROM at_auction AS a JOIN at_brands AS b ON a.aCarBrandID = b.bid WHERE bid = '{$bid}' ORDER BY b.brand $orderx";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic WHERE 1=1 and if you want to insert additional condition:

```
$query_AUCTION = "SELECT * 
          FROM at_auction AS a 
          JOIN at_brands AS b ON a.aCarBrandID = b.bid
          WHERE 1=1 ";

if ($bid > 0)
   $query_AUCTION .= " AND bid = '{$bid}' ";

$query_AUCTION .= " ORDER BY b.brand $orderx";
```

Comment: using WHERE 1=1 is bad practice. and not needed in this case

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$query_AUCTION = "SELECT * 
                  FROM at_auction AS a 
                  JOIN at_brands  AS b ON ( b.bid = a.aCarBrandID ) ";

if( isset( $_SESSION['bid'] ) )
{
    $query_AUCTION.= " WHERE b.bid = '".$_SESSION['bid']."'";
}

$query_AUCTION.= " ORDER BY b.brand $orderx";
```